# Many-to-many relations in entity framework causes infinite loop

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a data model in SQL Server which has a many-to-many-relationship. When Entity Framework models this relationship, it does that by creating a two-way list reference like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public ICollection<Class2> Class2s {get;set;}
}

public class Class2
{
    public ICollection<Class1> Class1s {get;set;}
}
```

Now the problem is that in some circumstances (but not all) this seems to cause an infinite loop. I have a case where when I call `Add()` on one of the collections, it causes the framework to loop back and forth between the get-methods of the properties in both classes, effectively hogging all CPU and freezing the app.

Have anyone experienced anything like this? What can I do to prevent it happening?

PS: I'm using [Rab Hallett's Mocking Framework generator](http://blogofrab.blogspot.com/2010/08/maintenance-free-mocking-for-unit.html) to generate the code. Don't know if this is relevant.

**Update 1**: It's definitely related to the mocking framework

**Update 2**: It's not an infinite loop, but it accesses all elements from both tables - probably causing n*m accesses. I will look more into it and get back

Comment: It definitely is related to Hallet's Mocking Framework. The behaviour is not reproducible with standard .NET Entity Framework code generation

Comment: Nilzor, can you confirm this? Would it be possible to run the same case on a context without the mocking framework?

Comment: The above comment was the confirmation. I have indeed run the same case on a context without the mocking framework. edit: So to solve my problem I have to a) fix or work around the bug, or b) find a different mockable object generator for EF

Comment: Of course! (Blush) totally overlooked the names... I left a comment at the framework's blog.

Answer (score 0):

As you say the infinate loop is in some cases only. This is probably a data problem.

If you take for example that class1 X has 3 class2's A, B, and C. If class2 A has in turn a class1 of X, then you have an infinate loop.

I have also encoutered this problem when using Automapper.

To fix it you can:

- Clean up the data, so that there are no infinate loops
- Add a counter that stops the loop after x iterations

Comment: Unfortunately the code that triggers the Get calls is in Entity Framework so I cannot change it. I cannot change the data structures either since they are a product of the code generation tool. I could change code generation tool though, and that is what I've done as of now. (See update1)